# Android TaskStackBuilder startActivities opens a white screen and freezes sometimes on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation, taskstackbuilder

I am getting a problem when trying to start an activity using the `startActivities()` method under `TaskStackBuilder` sometimes on some phones ( Specifically on *Samsung Galaxy S3 - Android 4.3 , Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo - Android 4.4.2*)

Below is the code snippet that is used:

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ConfirmAddressActivity.this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(AddressesActivity.class);

Intent intent = AddressesActivity.createStartingIntent(
    ConfirmAddressActivity.this,
    true, Collections.EMPTY_LIST
);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
stackBuilder.startActivities();
```

**The buggy behaviour**, is that after executing `stackBuilder.startActivities()` it opens a white screen and remains frozen without opening the AddressesActivity. This is not a regular behaviour, it happens sometimes.

**The normal behaviour**, is that after executing `stackBuilder.startActivities()` it opens a white screen for (0.5 second - 1 second) then opens the AddressesActivity while the full back stack of that activity had been built correctly.
This is the correct behaviour under many devices/platforms. (*HTC M9 Android 6.0 , Samsung S2 - Android 4.1.2 , Samsung Galaxy S6 - Android 5.1.1 , LG G4 - Android 5.1.1*)

Here is the android manifest snippet that defines the activities:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.account.AccountActivity"
    android:label="My account"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName=".activity.DashboardActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".activity.DashboardActivity" />
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".activity.addresses.AddressesActivity"
    android:label="My addresses"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName=".activity.account.AccountActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.account.AccountActivity" />
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".activity.addresses.ConfirmAddressActivity"
    android:label="Save address"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName=".activity.addresses.AddressDetailsActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.addresses.AddressDetailsActivity" />
</activity>
```

Any help or insight on this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, did you find any solutions?

Comment: What is the code in its onCreate method? Have you tried this code with a simple hello world activity?